# Android WebRTC Randomly crashes with Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 1191 (TimeCheckThread), pid 656 (audioserver)

Tags: android, webrtc, openvidu

My WebRTC randomly crashes with Fatal signal 6 error. Specially on low networks. Can anyone please tell me what the reason can be or has any idea. I'm using Openvidu Android Client for WebRTC implementation.

Stack Trace :

```
01-18 18:33:44.275 F/libc    (  656): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 1191 (TimeCheckThread), pid 656 (audioserver)
01-18 18:33:44.445 F/DEBUG   (10961): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-18 18:33:44.445 F/DEBUG   (10961): Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdm710/sdm710:9/MyCompany_1.6_0902/ubuntu09021542:user/test-keys'
01-18 18:33:44.445 F/DEBUG   (10961): Revision: '0'
01-18 18:33:44.445 F/DEBUG   (10961): ABI: 'arm'
01-18 18:33:44.445 F/DEBUG   (10961): pid: 656, tid: 1191, name: TimeCheckThread  >>> /system/bin/audioserver <<<
01-18 18:33:44.445 F/DEBUG   (10961): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-18 18:33:44.445 F/DEBUG   (10961): Abort message: 'TimeCheck timeout for IAudioPolicyService: 1'
01-18 18:33:44.446 F/DEBUG   (10961):     r0  00000000  r1  000004a7  r2  00000006  r3  e6406568
01-18 18:33:44.446 F/DEBUG   (10961):     r4  00000290  r5  000004a7  r6  e1a494a4  r7  0000010c
01-18 18:33:44.446 F/DEBUG   (10961):     r8  e174f76c  r9  e389e428  r10 e62efccc  r11 3b9aca00
01-18 18:33:44.446 F/DEBUG   (10961):     ip  e64103cc  sp  e1a49490  lr  e637c245  pc  e6373036
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, looks like this issue was device specific and required some configurations.
From logs its clear that device's audioserver was crashing on a very rudimentary level.
I switched from using MODE_IN_CALL to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION for speakerphone and mic both and this issue disappeared. It's a weird issue and the solution is even weirder but it works.
The device I was using was a AR Smart Glass that has a mic continuously 'on' to listen to your voice commands, I think that was the culprit or maybe misconfigured hardware drivers.